# Using regular expressions in shell script

Tags: regex, linux, shell

What is the correct way to parse a string using regular expressions in a linux shell script? I wrote the following script to print my SO rep on the console using `curl` and `sed` (not solely because I'm rep-crazy - I'm trying to learn some shell scripting and regex before switching to linux).

```
json=$(curl -s http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/165297.json)
echo $json | sed 's/.*"reputation":"\([0-9,]\{1,\}\)".*/\1/' | sed s/,//
```

But somehow I feel that `sed` is not the proper tool to use here. I heard that `grep` is all about regex and explored it a bit. But apparently it prints the whole line whenever a match is found - I am trying to extract a number from a single line of text. Here is a downsized version of the string that I'm working on (returned by `curl`).

> {"displayName":"Amarghosh","reputation":"2,737","badgeHtml":"\u003cspan title=\"1 silver badge\"\u003e\u003cspan class=\"badge2\"\u003e&#9679;\u003c/span\u003e\u003cspan class=\"badgecount\"\u003e1\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/span\u003e"}

I guess my questions are:

- What is the correct way to parse a string using regular expressions in a linux shell script?
- Is `sed` the right thing to use here?
- Could this be done using `grep`?
- Is there any other command that's more easier/appropriate?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `grep` command will select the desired line(s) from many but it will not directly manipulate the line. For that, you use `sed` in a pipeline:

```
someCommand | grep 'Amarghosh' | sed -e 's/foo/bar/g'
```

Alternatively, `awk` (or `perl` if available) can be used. It's a far more powerful text processing tool than `sed` in my opinion.

```
someCommand | awk '/Amarghosh/ { do something }'
```

For simple text manipulations, just stick with the `grep/sed` combo. When you need more complicated processing, move on up to `awk` or `perl`.

My first thought is to just use:

```
echo '{"displayName":"Amarghosh","reputation":"2,737","badgeHtml"'
    | sed -e 's/.*tion":"//' -e 's/".*//' -e 's/,//g'
```

which keeps the number of `sed` processes to one (you can give multiple commands with `-e`).

Comment: I'm a Perl guy myself, but sometimes awk is faster and cleaner for extracting data. It does one thing and it does it pretty well :)

Comment: @hobbs: you like parsing JSON with regular expressions, but not HTML?

Comment: Thanks pax. @Kinopiko I think that would be because json has a solid structure, but html can be totally out of structure (missing closing braces etc).

Comment: You obviously don't know `sed`.  It both has loops and can do the selects itself.  It is just as "powerful" as (albeit less convenient than) `awk`, and certainly better than `grep`.

Comment: I know sed well enough to know awk is better for more complex tasks :-) If you're talking about sed's branch and test commands, they're a horrible kludge, nothing like awk's elegant for statement (similar to C). Any Turing-complete language is as "powerful" as any other but I'd still rather write my applications in Java than machine language.

Comment: Amarghosh, it doesn't matter whether the structure is "solid" or not, what matters is where the language sits in the Chomsky hierarchy.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy  JSON, like HTML can not be properly parsed by a pure regex. JSON is at least a context-free language, if not higher on the hierarchy.

Comment: Amarghosh, Regular expressions (which specify discrete finite automata) parse only regular languages.  JSON is not a regular language, so you must use a more powerful automaton (turing machine) to parse the code.

Comment: @daotoad I see what you mean. My question was more about the right tools to use while parsing strings with regex in a shell script. I still believe it should be possible to parse json with regex though, since it has a solid structure.

Answer (score 8):

You may be interested in using Perl for such tasks. As a demonstration, here is a Perl script which prints the number you want:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use LWP::Simple;
use JSON;

my $url = "http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/165297.json";
my $flair = get ($url);
my $parsed = from_json ($flair);
print "$parsed->{reputation}\n";
```

This script requires you to install the JSON module, which you can do with just the command `cpan JSON`.

Answer (score 5):

For working with JSON in shell script, use [jsawk](http://github.com/micha/jsawk) which *like awk, but for JSON*.

```
json=$(curl -s http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/165297.json)
echo $json | jsawk 'return this.reputation' # 2,747
```

Comment: Thanks. Though I think regex is enough for this particular case, it's good to know that there is a json parser for the shell.

Answer (score 3):

My proposition:

```
$ echo $json | sed 's/,//g;s/^.*reputation...\([0-9]*\).*$/\1/'
```

I put two commands in sed argument:

- `s/,//g` is used to remove all commas, in particular the ones that are present in the reputation value.
- `s/^.*reputation...\([0-9]*\).*$/\1/` locates the reputation value in the line and replaces the whole line by that value.

In this particular case, I find that `sed` provides the most compact command without loss of readability.

Other tools for manipulating strings (not only regex) include:

- `grep`, `awk`, `perl` mentioned in most of other answers
- `tr` for replacing characters
- `cut`, `paste` for handling multicolumn inputs
- `bash` itself with its rich `$(...)` syntax for accessing variables
- `tail`, `head` for keeping last or first lines of a file

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that we can pass more than one command to sed.

Answer (score 2):

`sed` is appropriate, but you'll spawn a new process for every `sed` you use (which may be too heavyweight in more complex scenarios). `grep` is not really appropriate. It's a search tool that uses regexps to find lines of interest.

[Perl](http://www.perl.com) is one appropriate solution here, being a shell scripting language with powerful regexp features. It'll do most everything you need without spawning out to separate processes (unlike normal Unix shell scripting) and has a huge library of additional functions.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with grep. There is -o switch in grep witch extract only matching string not whole line.

```
$ echo $json | grep -o '"reputation":"[0-9,]\+"' | grep -o '[0-9,]\+'
2,747
```

Comment: a challenge. how about doing it with just one grep command :)

Comment: @qba thanks for the `-o`. @ghoshdog74 Using one grep and a sed would be cheating, right ;)

Comment: I think lookbehind is the way to go. Something like `(?<=reputation":")[0-9,]+` But I don't know if look behind is supported in shell's regex - the given pattern didn't work for me. May be I am not escaping all special characters.

Comment: @Amarghosh - cheating?? Don't know what you mean. Anyway , my point is: if you can do it in one invocation of grep, why do it 2 times ...

Answer (score 2):

> #### 1)  What is the correct way to parse a string using regular expressions in a linux shell script?

Tools that include regular expression capabilities include sed, grep, awk, Perl, Python, to mention a few. Even newer version of Bash have regex capabilities. All you need to do is look up the docs on how to use them.

> #### 2) Is sed the right thing to use here?

It can be, but not necessary.

> #### 3) Could this be done using grep?

Yes it can. you will just construct similar regex as you would if you use sed, or others. Note that grep just does what it does, and if you want to modify any files, it will not do it for you.

> #### 4) Is there any other command that's easier/more appropriate?

Of course. regex can be powerful, but its not necessarily the best tool to use everytime. It also depends on what you mean by "easier/appropriate". 
The other method to use with minimal fuss on regex is using the fields/delimiter approach. you look for patterns that can be "splitted". for eg, in your case(i have downloaded the 165297.json file instead of using curl..(but its the same)

```
awk 'BEGIN{
 FS="reputation" # split on the word "reputation"
}
{
    m=split($2,a,"\",\"")    # field 2 will contain the value you want plus the rest
                             # Then split on ":" and save to array "a"
    gsub(/[:\",]/,"",a[1])   # now, get rid of the redundant characters
    print a[1]
}' 165297.json
```

output:

```
$ ./shell.sh
2747
```

Comment: "easier/appropriate" - I am looking for the way people normally do string parsing with regex in shell scripts. This is my first shell script and I wrote this with a lot of help from online man pages. Wanted to make sure this is the normal way to do this.

Comment: the only tool you will ever need to do string/text parsing, is awk.

Comment: wrt the comment in @qba's answer: I can't seem to do it with a single invocation of grep - how to do it?

Comment: just combine the 2nd grep's regex with the first grep's regex, which sad to say i am not going to bother myself to come up with. I will let qba give you the answer

Answer (score 1):

`sed` is a perfectly valid command for your task, but it may not be the only one.

`grep` may be useful too, but as you say it prints the whole line. It's most useful for filtering the lines of a multi-line file, and discarding the lines you don't want.

Efficient shell scripts can use a combination of commands (not just the two you mentioned), exploiting the talents of each.

Answer (score 0):

Blindly:

```
echo $json | awk -F\" '{print $8}'
```

Similar (the field separator can be a regex):

```
awk -F'{"|":"|","|"}' '{print $5}'
```

Smarter (look for the key and print its value):

```
awk -F'{"|":"|","|"}' '{for(i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) if ($i == "reputation") print $(i+1)}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a proper library (as others noted):

`E:\Home> perl -MLWP::Simple -MJSON -e "print from_json(get 'http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/165297.json')->{reputation}"`

or

`$ perl -MLWP::Simple -MJSON -e 'print from_json(get "http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/165297.json")->{reputation}, "\n"'`

depending on OS/shell combination.

Answer (score 0):

## Simple RegEx via Shell

Disregarding the specific code in question, there may be times when you want to do a quick regex replace-all from stdin to stdout using shell, in a simple way, using a string syntax similar to JavaScript.

Below are some examples for anyone looking for a way to do this. Perl is a better bet on Mac since it lacks some sed options. If you want to get stdin as a variable you can use `MY_VAR=$(cat);`.

`echo 'text' | perl -pe 's/search/replace/g'; # using perl`
`echo 'text' | sed -e 's/search/replace/g';   # using sed`

And here's an example of a custom, reusable regex function. Arguments are *source string* (or -- for stdin), *search*, *replace*, and *options*.

```
regex() {
    case "$#" in
        ( '0' ) exit 1 ;; ( '1' ) echo "$1"; exit 0 ;;
        ( '2' ) REP='' ;; ( '3' ) REP="$3"; OPT='' ;;
        ( * ) REP="$3"; OPT="$4" ;;
    esac
    TXT="$1"; SRCH="$2";
    if [ "$1" = "--" ]; then [ ! -t 0 ] && read -r TXT; fi
    echo "$TXT" | perl -pe 's/'"$SRCH"'/'"$REP"'/'"$OPT";
}
```

`echo 'text' | regex -- search replace g;`