# Go examples and idioms

Tags: go

There's not a lot of Go code to learn the language from, and I'm sure I'm not the only one experimenting with it. So, if you found out something interesting about the language, please post an example here.

I'm also looking for

- idiomatic ways to do things in Go,
- C/C++ style of thinking "ported" to Go,
- common pitfalls about the syntax,
- anything interesting, really.

Comment: Did you watch [this talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rKnDgT73v8s)? It shows a lot of cool stuff you can do (end of the talk)

Comment: ARM support such as 8-bit or 16-bit. D language still do not.

Comment: The library (http://golang.org/pkg/) is an excellent source to learn how go is used. Personally, I find that learning how data structures are implemented is helpful to learn the language.

Answer (score 35):

**Defer statements**

> A "defer" statement invokes a function whose execution is deferred to the moment the surrounding function returns.
>
> DeferStmt = "defer" Expression .
>
> The expression must be a function or method call. Each time the "defer" statement executes, the parameters to the function call are evaluated and saved anew but the function is not invoked. Deferred function calls are executed in LIFO order immediately before the surrounding function returns, but after the return values, if any, have been evaluated.

```
lock(l);
defer unlock(l);  // unlocking happens before surrounding function returns

// prints 3 2 1 0 before surrounding function returns
for i := 0; i <= 3; i++ {
    defer fmt.Print(i);
}
```

**Update:**

`defer` is now also the idiomatic way to handle `panic` in an [exception-like](http://blog.golang.org/2010/08/defer-panic-and-recover.html) manner:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    f()
    fmt.Println("Returned normally from f.")
}

func f() {
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            fmt.Println("Recovered in f", r)
        }
    }()
    fmt.Println("Calling g.")
    g(0)
    fmt.Println("Returned normally from g.")
}

func g(i int) {
    if i > 3 {
        fmt.Println("Panicking!")
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("%v", i))
    }
    defer fmt.Println("Defer in g", i)
    fmt.Println("Printing in g", i)
    g(i+1)
}
```

Comment: Looks like good old RAII (made explicit).

Comment: +1 since I read a lot about Go, but I still didn't see this (until you showed me)!

Comment: Clever, although it would make more sense to me if defer statements where executed in FIFO order (top to bottom), but maybe that's just me...

Comment: Cool. Reminds me of scrop guards from D http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/exception-safe.html

Comment: @Mike: if you compare with blocks of "try:..finally:" LIFO nests in the same way. For resource open/close pairs etc, nesting like this is the only thing that makes sense (First open will close last).

Comment: @kaizer: I guess it depends how you read the `defer` statements in your head :). Since it's in LIFO order, you have to read it "backwards" to see how it's releasing things (`defer CloseDatabase; defer CloseTable` means "Close the database AFTER you close the table"). If I didn't know any better, I would have written it as `defer CloseTable; defer CloseDatabase` because my first instinct would be to read it as "Close the table first, THEN close the database."). But backwards to me is correct to someone else ;)

Comment: Like Kinopiko, I wonder what this is good for in real life?

Comment: No, @KonradRudolph, RAII is about objects termination, not just functions. "Defer" is more like try-catch.

Comment: @OZ_ RAII is only superficially about object termination. RAII is used to implement the same thing that you get from `try`–`finally` (*not* `catch`). They are not the same but they are used to support the same semantics. Put differently: where you’d use `defer` in Go you’d use RAII in languages that support it (mainly C++).

Comment: @KonradRudolph absolutely no. You don't understand what is RAII. Try to implement mutexes with try-catch (it will be funny).

Comment: @OZ_ I’m sorry but you have it the wrong way round. I do understand RAII (just search Stack Overflow for [my contributions on the subject](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/raii/topusers)), but I don’t know what you mean by implementing a mutex via try–catch, I never suggested doing that. You can trivially do it via try–finally, though.

Comment: @KonradRudolph then google little bit about mutexes and RAII :) You tried to prove that `defer` is the same thing as RAII, even despite of fact that `defer` works just in scope of function. So I tried to show you that with RAII you can do things which are much more hard to implement without RAII. Enough about it. If you still think RAII and `defer` is the same thing - we have nothing to talk about.

Comment: @OZ_ I never tried to prove that RAII is strictly the same as `defer`,  just that they are used to solve the same problems. But if you want to have a mutex with `defer`, it’s easy enough (it’s a standard example of using a handle with try–finally, and trivially adaptable to `defer`): `m := mutex{}; defer m.unlock(); m.lock();` – I hope I got the Go syntax right: I never use it, but I use the same routinely in R (`defer` there is called `on.exit`).

Answer (score 25):

Go object files actually include a cleartext header:

```
jurily@jurily ~/workspace/go/euler31 $ 6g euler31.go
jurily@jurily ~/workspace/go/euler31 $ cat euler31.6
amd64
  exports automatically generated from
  euler31.go in package "main"
    import

$$  // exports
  package main
    var main.coin [9]int
    func main.howmany (amount int, max int) (? int)
    func main.main ()
    var main.initdone· uint8
    func main.init ()

$$  // local types
  type main.dsigddd_1·1 struct { ? int }

$$

!
<binary segment>
```

Comment: That's more like a hidden feature than an idiomatic example

Answer (score 22):

I have seen a couple of people complaining about the for-loop, along the lines of "why should we have to say `i = 0; i < len; i++` in this day and age?".

I disagree, I like the for construct. You can use the long version if you wish, but the idiomatic Go is

```
var a = []int{1, 2, 3}
for i, v := range a {
    fmt.Println(i, v)
}
```

The `for .. range` construct loops over all the elements and supplies two values - the index `i` and the value `v`.

`range` also works on maps and channels.

Still, if you dislike `for` in any form, you can define `each`, `map` etc. in a few lines:

```
type IntArr []int

// 'each' takes a function argument.
// The function must accept two ints, the index and value,
// and will be called on each element in turn.
func (a IntArr) each(fn func(index, value int)) {
    for i, v := range a {
        fn(i, v)
    }
}

func main() {
    var a = IntArr([]int{2, 0, 0, 9}) // create int slice and cast to IntArr
    var fnPrint = func(i, v int) {
        fmt.Println(i, ":", v)
    } // create a function

    a.each(fnPrint) // call on each element
}
```

prints

```
0 : 2
1 : 0
2 : 0
3 : 9
```

I'm starting to like Go a lot :)

Comment: Though `range` is only nice, if it is compiled to the same code as the for-3 loop.

Answer (score 19):

Here's a nice example of iota from [Kinopiko's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712172/whats-your-take-on-the-programming-language-go/1712502#1712502):

```
type ByteSize float64
const (
    _ = iota;   // ignore first value by assigning to blank identifier
    KB ByteSize = 1<<(10*iota)
    MB
    GB
    TB
    PB
    YB
)

// This implicitly repeats to fill in all the values (!)
```

Comment: Note that the semicolons are unnecessary.

Answer (score 19):

## Go and get your stackoverflow reputation

This is a translation of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636352/using-regular-expressions-in-shell-script/1636508#1636508).

```
package main

import (
    "json"
    "fmt"
    "http"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func die(message string) {
    fmt.Printf("%s.\n", message);
    os.Exit(1);
}

func main() {
    kinopiko_flair := "https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/181548.json"
    response, _, err := http.Get(kinopiko_flair)
    if err != nil {
        die(fmt.Sprintf("Error getting %s", kinopiko_flair))
    }

    var nr int
    const buf_size = 0x1000
    buf := make([]byte, buf_size)

    nr, err = response.Body.Read(buf)
    if err != nil && error != os.EOF {
        die(fmt.Sprintf("Error reading response: %s", err.String()))
    }
    if nr >= buf_size { die ("Buffer overrun") }
    response.Body.Close()

    json_text := strings.Split(string(buf), "\000", 2)
    parsed, ok, errtok := json.StringToJson(json_text[0])
    if ! ok {
        die(fmt.Sprintf("Error parsing JSON %s at %s", json_text, errtok))
    }

    fmt.Printf("Your stackoverflow.com reputation is %s\n", parsed.Get ("reputation"))
}
```

Thanks to [Scott Wales for help with .Read ().](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721212/how-do-i-use-the-read-function-in-go/1721364#1721364)

This looks fairly clunky still, with the two strings and two buffers, so if any Go experts have advice, let me know.

Comment: I'm not sure what was supposed to be wrong with the formatting; I've restored it.

Comment: The Go authors recommend to `gofmt` your code :-)

Comment: I can't compile it:

      $ ../go/src/cmd/6g/6g SO.go
        SO.go:34: undefined: json.StringToJson

Comment: @Raphink: the language has changed since I made this.

Comment: Yeah, do you know maybe what's the closest equivalent to the StringToJson? It used to set up a builder internally, now one has to provide their own with a predefined native structure?

Answer (score 18):

Here's an idiom from the [Effective Go](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#switch) page

```
switch {
case '0' <= c && c <= '9':
    return c - '0'
case 'a' <= c && c <= 'f':
    return c - 'a' + 10
case 'A' <= c && c <= 'F':
    return c - 'A' + 10
}
return 0
```

The switch statement switches on true when no expression is given. So this is equivalent to

```
if '0' <= c && c <= '9' {
    return c - '0'
} else if 'a' <= c && c <= 'f' {
    return c - 'a' + 10
} else if 'A' <= c && c <= 'F' {
    return c - 'A' + 10
}
return 0
```

At the moment, the switch version looks a little cleaner to me.

Comment: Whoa, completely ripped of from VB. ;-) (`Switch True` …)

Comment: @Konrad, beat me to it! :) I've used that idiom in VB6 code before and it definitely can help readability in certain situations.

Comment: What is '<='? Is it related to '<-' ?

Comment: @Raphink: less-than-or-equals.

Answer (score 18):

You can swap variables by parallel assignment:

```
x, y = y, x

// or in an array
a[j], a[i] = a[i], a[j]
```

simple but effective.

Answer (score 17):

[Type switches](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Type_switches):

```
switch i := x.(type) {
case nil:
    printString("x is nil");
case int:
    printInt(i);  // i is an int
case float:
    printFloat(i);  // i is a float
case func(int) float:
    printFunction(i);  // i is a function
case bool, string:
    printString("type is bool or string");  // i is an interface{}
default:
    printString("don't know the type");
}
```

Answer (score 16):

When importing packages, you can redefine the name to anything you want:

```
package main

import f "fmt"

func main() {
    f.Printf("Hello World\n")
}
```

Comment: I've already made use of this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726698/code-golf-sierpinskis-triangle/1727227#1727227

Answer (score 14):

From [James Antill's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730719/how-do-i-find-out-if-a-goroutine-is-done-without-blocking/1731488#1731488):

```
foo := <-ch     // This blocks.
foo, ok := <-ch // This returns immediately.
```

Also, a potential pitfall: the [subtle difference](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Communication_operators) between the receive and send operators:

```
a <- ch // sends ch to channel a
<-ch    // reads from channel ch
```

Comment: The receive operator itself **is** now a blocking operation, as of Go 1.0.3 . The spec has been modified : http://golang.org/ref/spec#Receive_operator . Please try the blocking behavior (deadlock) here : http://play.golang.org/p/0yurtWW4Q3

Answer (score 14):

**Named result parameters**

> The return or result "parameters" of a
>   Go function can be given names and
>   used as regular variables, just like
>   the incoming parameters. When named,
>   they are initialized to the zero
>   values for their types when the
>   function begins; if the function
>   executes a return statement with no
>   arguments, the current values of the
>   result parameters are used as the
>   returned values.
>
> The names are not mandatory but they
>   can make code shorter and clearer:
>   they're documentation. If we name the
>   results of nextInt it becomes obvious
>   which returned int is which.

```
func nextInt(b []byte, pos int) (value, nextPos int) {
```

> Because named results are initialized and tied to an unadorned return, they can simplify as well as clarify. Here's a version of io.ReadFull that uses them well:

```
func ReadFull(r Reader, buf []byte) (n int, err os.Error) {
    for len(buf) > 0 && err == nil {
        var nr int;
        nr, err = r.Read(buf);
        n += nr;
        buf = buf[nr:len(buf)];
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: I'm curious -- does any other language have this?

Comment: Matlab has something similar.

Comment: pascal uses similar syntax for returning one value.

Comment: @nes1983 For those who don't know, in Pascal you classically assign the return value to the function name.

Comment: FORTRAN pretty much has this.

Answer (score 13):

```
/* 
 * How many different ways can £2 be made using any number of coins?
 * Now with 100% less semicolons!
 */

package main
import "fmt"


/* This line took me over 10 minutes to figure out.
 *  "[...]" means "figure out the size yourself"
 * If you only specify "[]", it will try to create a slice, which is a reference to an existing array.
 * Also, ":=" doesn't work here.
 */
var coin = [...]int{0, 1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200}

func howmany(amount int, max int) int {
    if amount == 0 { return 1 }
    if amount < 0 { return 0 }
    if max <= 0 && amount >= 1 { return 0 }

    // recursion works as expected
    return howmany(amount, max-1) + howmany(amount-coin[max], max)
}


func main() {
    fmt.Println(howmany(200, len(coin)-1))
}
```

Comment: I would suggest removing the name of the problem solving site as well as the id number. Maybe rephrase the question. As to not spoil the problem to someone stumbling over it. Or trying to cheat by searching for the problem on the net for that matter.

Comment: For the record: this is the algorithm from http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Coin_Change It's the first Google result for "coin change".

Answer (score 13):

I like that you can redefine types, including primitives like int, as many times as you like and attach different methods. Like defining a RomanNumeral type:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

var numText = "zero one two three four five six seven eight nine ten"
var numRoman = "- I II III IV V VI VII IX X"
var aText = strings.Split(numText, " ")
var aRoman = strings.Split(numRoman, " ")

type TextNumber int
type RomanNumber int

func (n TextNumber) String() string {
    return aText[n]
}

func (n RomanNumber) String() string {
    return aRoman[n]
}

func main() {
    var i = 5
    fmt.Println("Number: ", i, TextNumber(i), RomanNumber(i))
}
```

Which prints out

```
Number:  5 five V
```

The `RomanNumber()` call is essentially a cast, it redefines the int type as a more specific type of int. And `Println()` calls `String()` behind the scenes.

Answer (score 12):

### Returning a channel

This is a true idiom that is quite important: how to feed data into a channel and close it afterwards. With this you can make simple iterators (since range will accept a channel) or filters.

```
// return a channel that doubles the values in the input channel
func DoublingIterator(input chan int) chan int {
    outch := make(chan int);
    // start a goroutine to feed the channel (asynchronously)
    go func() {
        for x := range input {
            outch <- 2*x;    
        }
        // close the channel we created and control
        close(outch);
    }();
    return outch;
}
```

Comment: +1. Also, you can pass channels through channels as well.

Comment: But be careful not to break out of a for x := range chan {} loop, you'll leak the goroutine, and all the memory it references.

Comment: @JeffAllen how about `defer close(outch);` as the first statement of the goroutine?

Comment: Defer queues a statement for execution when the function returns, no matter which return point is taken. But if channel input is never closed, then the anonymous function in this example will never leave the for loop.

Answer (score 11):

```
for {
    v := <-ch
    if closed(ch) {
        break
    }
    fmt.Println(v)
}
```

Since range automatically checks for a closed channel, we can shorten to this:

```
for v := range ch {
    fmt.Println(v)
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Timeout for channel reads:

```
ticker := time.NewTicker(ns);
select {
    case v := <- chan_target:
        do_something_with_v;
    case <- ticker.C:
        handle_timeout;
}
```

Stolen from [Davies Liu](http://groups.google.com/group/golang-nuts/msg/2caddc5c7b7539f3).

Answer (score 9):

There is a make system set up that you can use in $GOROOT/src

Set up your makefile with

```
TARG=foobar           # Name of package to compile
GOFILES=foo.go bar.go # Go sources
CGOFILES=bang.cgo     # Sources to run cgo on
OFILES=a_c_file.$O    # Sources compiled with $Oc
                      # $O is the arch number (6 for x86_64)

include $(GOROOT)/src/Make.$(GOARCH)
include $(GOROOT)/src/Make.pkg
```

You can then use the automated testing tools by running make test, or add the package and shared objects from cgo to your $GOROOT with make install.

Answer (score 7):

This is an implementation of a stack. It illustrates adding methods onto a type.

I wanted to make the stack part of it into a slice and use the slice's properties, but although I got that to work without the `type`, I couldn't see the syntax for defining a slice with a `type`.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "os"

const stack_max = 100

type Stack2 struct {
    stack [stack_max]string
    size  int
}

func (s *Stack2) push(pushed_string string) {
    n := s.size
    if n >= stack_max-1 {
        fmt.Print("Oh noes\n")
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    s.size++
    s.stack[n] = pushed_string
}

func (s *Stack2) pop() string {
    n := s.size
    if n == 0 {
        fmt.Print("Underflow\n")
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    top := s.stack[n-1]
    s.size--
    return top
}

func (s *Stack2) print_all() {
    n := s.size
    fmt.Printf("Stack size is %d\n", n)
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("%d:\t%s\n", i, s.stack[i])
    }
}

func main() {
    stack := new(Stack2)
    stack.print_all()
    stack.push("boo")
    stack.print_all()
    popped := stack.pop()
    fmt.Printf("Stack top is %s\n", popped)
    stack.print_all()
    stack.push("moo")
    stack.push("zoo")
    stack.print_all()
    popped2 := stack.pop()
    fmt.Printf("Stack top is %s\n", popped2)
    stack.print_all()
}
```

Comment: Rather than using `fmt.Printf(...); os.Exit();`, you can use `panic(...)`.

Comment: That gives a stack trace, which I don't want.

Comment: Why is it limited? Go is a managed, gc'd language. Your stack can be as deep as you want. Use the new append() builtin, which will do something like C's realloc when it needs to.

Comment: "Go does not need generics", they said.

Answer (score 7):

Another interesting thing in Go is that `godoc`. You can run it as a web server on your computer using

```
godoc -http=:8080
```

where 8080 is the port number, and the entire website at golang.org is then available at `localhost:8080`.

Comment: Is this a regular program or a daemon?

Comment: It is a regular program.

Answer (score 4):

**Calling c code from go**

It's possible to access the lower level of go by using the c runtime.

C functions are in the form

```
void package·function(...)
```

(note the dot seperator is a unicode character) where the arguments may be basic go types, slices, strings etc. To return a value
call

```
FLUSH(&ret)
```

(you can return more than one value)

For instance, to create a function

```
package foo
bar( a int32, b string )(c float32 ){
    c = 1.3 + float32(a - int32(len(b))
}
```

in C you use

```
#include "runtime.h"
void foo·bar(int32 a, String b, float32 c){
    c = 1.3 + a - b.len;
    FLUSH(&c);
}
```

Note that you still should declare the function in a go file, and that you'll have to take care of memory yourself. I'm not sure if it's possible to call external libraries using this, it may be better to use cgo.

Look at $GOROOT/src/pkg/runtime for examples used in the runtime.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713214/how-to-use-c-in-go/1721230#1721230) for linking c++ code with go.

Comment: Does it use the "flying dot", really? I don't dare edit, but that seems a bit unexpected and radical.

Comment: Yes, you need to compile with 6c (or 8c, etc). I don't think gcc handles unicode identifiers.

Comment: I think AltGr+period types the same · but with unicode I'm not sure. Was very surprised to see that in source I read.. why not use something like ::?

Comment: The character is MIDDLE DOT U+00B7. The parser may have been fudged so that it sees this as a character in order to make a valid c identifier, which I believe would preclude ::.

Comment: The '·' is just a temporary hack, rob was even surprised it was still there, he said it was going to be replaced with something less idiosyncratic.

Comment: What language is that second code fragment written in?  It's neither go nor C.

Comment: The one with include "runtime.h" is c, I missed the hash. int32, String etc. are defined in the runtime header.

Comment: ALT + SHIFT + 9(not keypad) = '·' on OS X Mav

Answer (score 4):

Here is a go example using the sqlite3 package.

http://github.com/bikal/gosqlite-example

Answer (score 3):

```
const ever = true

for ever {
    // infinite loop
}
```

Comment: ahem. `for { /* infinite loop */ }` is enough.

Comment: Of course. That's exactly what's happening here. I just like the `forever` keyword. Even Qt has a macro for that.

Comment: but Go doesn't need a macro or a cute alias of true to do this.

Comment: @kaizer.se: Jurily's point is that `for ever` (after declaring the variable) is something cute you can do in Go if you want to. It looks like English (modulo the blank).

Comment: it is something cute you can do in C as well.. :-) `#define ever (;;)`

Answer (score 3):

A stack based on the other answer, but using slice appending to have no size limit.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "os"

type Stack2 struct {
        // initial storage space for the stack
        stack [10]string
        cur   []string
}

func (s *Stack2) push(pushed_string string) {
        s.cur = append(s.cur, pushed_string)
}

func (s *Stack2) pop() (popped string) {
        if len(s.cur) == 0 {
                fmt.Print("Underflow\n")
                os.Exit(1)
        }
        popped = s.cur[len(s.cur)-1]
        s.cur = s.cur[0 : len(s.cur)-1]
        return
}

func (s *Stack2) print_all() {
        fmt.Printf("Stack size is %d\n", len(s.cur))
        for i, s := range s.cur {
                fmt.Printf("%d:\t%s\n", i, s)
        }
}

func NewStack() (stack *Stack2) {
        stack = new(Stack2)
        // init the slice to an empty slice of the underlying storage
        stack.cur = stack.stack[0:0]
        return
}

func main() {
        stack := NewStack()
        stack.print_all()
        stack.push("boo")
        stack.print_all()
        popped := stack.pop()
        fmt.Printf("Stack top is %s\n", popped)
        stack.print_all()
        stack.push("moo")
        stack.push("zoo")
        stack.print_all()
        popped2 := stack.pop()
        fmt.Printf("Stack top is %s\n", popped2)
        stack.print_all()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of small programs in `test` in the main directory. Examples:

- `peano.go` prints factorials.
- `hilbert.go` has some matrix multiplication.
- `iota.go` has examples of the weird iota thing.