# How do I use the .Read function in Go?

Tags: go

Trying to use Go's http package, I can't work out the syntax of `.Read`. The following marked by HERE is the only thing I have got to compile, although I tried several other things which were all rejected by the compiler.

```
package main
import "fmt";
import "http";
import "os";

func main () {
    kinopiko_flair := "http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/181548.json";
    response, _, error := http.Get (kinopiko_flair);
    if (error != nil) {
        // I want to print out the error too.
        fmt.Printf ("Error getting %s\n", kinopiko_flair);
        os.Exit (1);
    }
    fmt.Printf ("Status is %s\n", response.Status);
    var nr int;
    var buf []byte;
    nr, error = response.Body.Read (buf); // HERE
    if (error != nil) {
        // I want to print out the error too.
        fmt.Printf ("Error reading response.\n");
        os.Exit (1);
    }
    response.Body.Close ();
    fmt.Printf ("Got %d bytes\n", nr);
    fmt.Printf ("Got '%s'\n", buf);
}
```

The URL is OK, since `wget` gets it fine, but when I run this `buf` is just an empty string and `nr` is always zero. What do I need to do to get the data out of `response`? The compiler rejected `.ReadAll` and other things I tried.

The output looks like this:

```
Status is 200 OK
Got 0 bytes
Got ''
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try giving the slice buf a size, e.g.

```
 buf := make([]byte,128);
```

Reader reads up to len() of the buffer it is given.

From io.go

```
// Reader is the interface that wraps the basic Read method.
//
// Read reads up to len(p) bytes into p.  It returns the number of bytes
// read (0 <= n <= len(p)) and any error encountered.
// Even if Read returns n < len(p),
// it may use all of p as scratch space during the call.
// If some data is available but not len(p) bytes, Read conventionally
// returns what is available rather than block waiting for more.
//
// At the end of the input stream, Read returns 0, os.EOF.
// Read may return a non-zero number of bytes with a non-nil err.
// In particular, a Read that exhausts the input may return n > 0, os.EOF.
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to adapt the cat example from the tutorial:

```
fmt.Printf ("Status is %s\n", response.Status);
var nr int;

const NBUF = 512;
var buf [NBUF]byte;

for {
    switch nr, _ := response.Body.Read(&buf); true {
    case nr < 0:
        os.Exit(1);
    case nr == 0:  // EOF
        return;
    case nr > 0:
        if nw, _ := os.Stdout.Write(buf[0:nr]); nw != nr {
            fmt.Printf("error\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./8.out 
Status is 200 OK
{"id":181548,"gravatarHtml":"\u003cimg src=\"http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f4a286fa31d1359ee92113823a70a738?s=50&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=PG\" height=\"50\" width=\"50\" alt=\"\"\u003e","profileUrl":"http://stackoverflow.com/users/181548/kinopiko","displayName":"Kinopiko","reputation":"4,674","badgeHtml":"\u003cspan title=\"1 gold badge\"\u003e\u003cspan class=\"badge1\"\u003e&#9679;\u003c/span\u003e\u003cspan class=\"badgecount\"\u003e1\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003cspan title=\"5 silver badges\"\u003e\u003cspan class=\"badge2\"\u003e&#9679;\u003c/span\u003e\u003cspan class=\"badgecount\"\u003e5\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003cspan title=\"21 bronze badges\"\u003e\u003cspan class=\"badge3\"\u003e&#9679;\u003c/span\u003e\u003cspan class=\"badgecount\"\u003e21\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/span\u003e"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here size of buf is not defined so buf is created with 0 size.
creating buf with some size should help.
buf = make([]byte, 500)

```
$ cat slice.go 
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    kinopiko_flair := "http://stackoverflow.com"
    response, error := http.Get(kinopiko_flair)
    if error != nil {
        // I want to print out the error too.
        fmt.Printf("Error getting %s\n", kinopiko_flair)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Status is %s\n", response.Status)
    var nr int
    var buf []byte
    fmt.Printf("Initially :capacity of slice is %d and length is %d \n ", cap(buf), len(buf))
    buf = make([]byte, 500) // THIS SHOULD HELP
    fmt.Printf("UPDATE: capacity of slice is %d and length is %d \n ", cap(buf), len(buf))
    nr, error = response.Body.Read(buf) // HERE
    if error != nil {
        // I want to print out the error too.
        fmt.Printf("Error reading response.\n")
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    response.Body.Close()
    fmt.Printf("Got %d bytes\n", nr)
    fmt.Printf("Got '%s'\n", buf)
}
```

## Output

```
$ go run slice.go 
    Status is 200 OK
     Initially :capacity of slice is 0 and length is 0 
     UPDATE: capacity of slice is 500 and length is 500 
     Got 500 bytes
    Got '<!DOCTYPE html>


        <html class="html__responsive html__unpinned-leftnav">

        <head>

            <title>Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, &amp; Build Careers</title>
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=4f32ecc8f43d">
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon image_src" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a">
            <link rel="search" type="application/opensear'
```