# How do I find out if a goroutine is done, without blocking?

Tags: go, signals-slots, goroutine

All the examples I've seen so far involve blocking to get the result (via the `<-chan` operator).

My current approach involves passing a pointer to a struct:

```
type goresult struct {
    result resultType;
    finished bool;
}
```

which the goroutine writes upon completion. Then it's a simple matter of checking `finished` whenever convenient. Do you have better alternatives?

What I'm really aiming for is a Qt-style signal-slot system. I have a hunch the solution will look almost trivial (`chan`s have *lots* of unexplored potential), but I'm not yet familiar enough with the language to figure it out.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the "comma, ok" pattern (see their page on "[effective go](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html)"):

```
foo     := <- ch; // This blocks.
foo, ok := <- ch; // This returns immediately.
```

Comment: you have to write:
select {
case foo := <-ch:
default:
}

Answer (score 6):

[Select statements](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Select_statements) allows you to check multiple channels at once, taking a random branch (of the ones where communication is waiting):

```
func main () {
    for {
    select {
        case w := <- workchan:
            go do_work(w)
        case <- signalchan:
            return
        // default works here if no communication is available
        default:
            // do idle work
    }
    }
}
```

> For all the send and receive
>   expressions in the "select" statement,
>   the channel expressions are evaluated,
>   along with any expressions that appear
>   on the right hand side of send
>   expressions, in top-to-bottom order.
>   If any of the resulting operations can
>   proceed, one is chosen and the
>   corresponding communication and
>   statements are evaluated. Otherwise,
>   if there is a default case, that
>   executes; if not, the statement blocks
>   until one of the communications can
>   complete.

Comment: @Jurily: Are you sure about that? It should be correct, but would look better without the space after `<-`.

Answer (score 5):

You can also peek at the channel buffer to see if it contains anything by using len:

```
if len(channel) > 0 {
  // has data to receive
}
```

This won't touch the channel buffer, unlike `foo, gotValue := <- ch` which removes a value when `gotValue == true`.